# Filled contour plot hides line plot in matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a surface, its filled contour with an offset (in order to appear at the bottom of the plot) and a line all in the same matplotlib 3D plot. The code I'm using is the following:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-0.5, levels=levels)
ax.plot(xs, ys, np.full_like(xs, -0.5))

ax.set_zlim(-0.5, 0.5)

plt.show()
```

Where X, Y and Z are the variables for the surface and xs and ys are the variables for the line.

The problem is that the filled contour hides the line plot. The plot I get is the following:

[image]

When I change the alpha of the filled contour to 0.5 I can see the line, as can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

But I want the filled contour to have an alpha value of 1.0 and to see the line. I've tried changing the value of the 'zorder' parameter of the filled contour and the line, but nothing changes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Another case of the [matplotlib 3D FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html), section "My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles".